# no data in mongodb after insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Everything works fine when I insert data to database. But I can't find the data inserted in robo 3T interface.....

code:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp',{ useNewUrlParser: true },(err,client) =>{
    if(err) {
        return console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDB server');
    }
    console.log('Connected MongoDB server');
    const db = client.db('TodoApp');

    db.collection('Todos').insertOne({
        text: 'Something to do',
        completed: false
    },(err,result) => {
        if(err){
            return console.log('Unable to insert todo',err);
        }

        console.log(JSON.stringify(result.ops,undefined,2));
    });

     client.close();
});
```

[image: it is the terminal result after I run js code]

[image: this is the Robo 3T interface where I can not find the data I inserted]

Comment: Right click on your DB on the left and select 'Refresh'

Comment: it does not work.....  I tried several times before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you nodejs URL you are connecting to the ’TodoApp’ database and in your robomongo, you are connected to the ’test’ database